# API requests works in the Web site But not work in python requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I go onto this webpage

https://iso19139echnap.geocat.live/geonetwork/doc/api/index.html#/records/getRecord

and try this API call under Records/get/get a metadata record.

[image]

Worked,

[image]

However if I try to call the API in python, it responds `403`

```
import requests
url_metadata = "https://iso19139echnap.geocat.live/geonetwork/srv/api/0.1/records/d1ec996c-d21c-4bc4-9888-6f1722b44a57"

headers = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
"Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
"Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.9",
"Connection": "keep-alive",
"Cookie": "XSRF-TOKEN=97bb29dd-9165-4fd4-bbd1-e2c72bffa509; JSESSIONID=78C1024AF960D630A4EA49DA02DFC89A; serverTime=1615580729954; sessionExpiry=1615582829954",
"Host": "iso19139echnap.geocat.live",
"Referer": "https://iso19139echnap.geocat.live/geonetwork/doc/api/index.html",
"Sec-Fetch-Dest": "empty",
"Sec-Fetch-Mode": "cors",
"Sec-Fetch-Site": "same-origin",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.72 Safari/537.36 Edg/89.0.774.45",
"Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    }
payload = {}


r_metadata = requests.request("GET", url_metadata, headers=headers, data=payload)
print("single metadata api status: "+ str(r_metadata))
```

Comment: It's usually Javascript is the problem.

Comment: 403 is an authentication problem, if you are using a rest api, maybe there is a POST request to authenticate.

Comment: API may use different cookies in every request so hardcoded cookies may not work.

Comment: APIs usually doesn't need all these headers - they are created to get data with scripts/programs so they don't check `User-Agent`, etc. Often they needs only `Accept` to send data in correct format.

Comment: in code you use different `metadataUuid` - when I use it on web page then I get error 404

Comment: APIs usually need authorization. Maybe web page works only  when you loged in. Besides it is pages created specially for test/learn it and it may work with fake autorization but in code you may have to first send `client_ID`, `client_SECRET` to get access to data on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an authentication problem, you need to include `X-XSRF-TOKEN` as a header. please refer to this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/389234/82693) on how to send a request to GeoNetwork from an API client.